# keeping radio label in div and mouseoverstate for radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, radio-button

http://jsfiddle.net/4QZED/6/ . attempting to create 3 states for a radio selected unselected and hover/mouseover. each off this states are css/div/button. but trying to make the label the button, to keep the label text in the button.

prefer css instead of a jpg to avoid image degrading when page is zoomed.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>");
        } else { 
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>");
        }
    });

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.radioButtonOff').add('.radioButtonOn').toggleClass('radioButtonOff radioButtonOn');
    });

        /*  
 $(".radioButtonOff").mouseover(function() {
       if ($(this)toggle('.radioButtonHover');
    });

  $("input[type=label]").change(function() {
         if($(this).find('#radiolabel');
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("input[type=label]").add(span);
         });
*/

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altered jQuery to simply pull the text from the label and add it to the dynamically appended div.

**EDIT:** I realize your if/else statement for the checked state was pointless since it wasn't altering anything at all based upon condition. You may have other plans for it, but based on the posted example, you could do away with the first portion of the jQuery entirely. I've made a small edit to the jquery code below.

```
 $("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this).parent("label").text();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOn'>" + lbl + "</div>");
        // something else here if radio is checked??
    } else { 
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'>" + lbl + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Added a span to the label HTML to hide the text.

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value="all"  />
    <span>All</span></label>
```

Changed CSS to allow hover state to work and hide label text.

```
.radioButtonOff { width: 60px; height: 20px; color: #fff; background: #333333;}
.radioButtonOff:hover, .radiobuttonOn:hover { width: 60px; color: #fff;height: 20px; background: #00a;}
.radioButtonOn { width: 60px; height: 20px; color: #fff;background: #a00;}
label span { display: none;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4QZED/9/)

Comment: I was over complicating the hover and wow so many commands out there, clever with the var. thank you.

Comment: thought i needed to use span, so close.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get this css to work in Chrome. Didn't test in other browsers, but should be decent.

```
label {position:relative; width:60px; height:20px; display:inline-block; line-height:20px; text-align:center;}
.radioButtonOff,.radioButtonHover,.radioButtonOn { width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:-1; }
.radioButtonOff { background: #333333;}
.radioButtonHover { background: #666666;}
.radioButtonOn { background: #999999;}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/P9m7q/

Comment: how did you get label to be decorated with radioButtonxxx? is it overlaying the label? very clean

Comment: it's overlaying, what i do w/ the radioButtonxxx is give it a negative z-index so it sits behind it. adding a hover would be very easy, `label:hover {color:#FFF}` or something like that would do it. be aware old versions of IE don't allow :hover on non <a>